# Return value from select using FreeMarker

Tags: java, spring-boot, freemarker, select-options

I have a form:

```
     <form action="user-fonts" method="post" ">
        <select >
        <#list fonts as font>
        <option value=${font}>${font.nameFont?ifExists}</option>
        </#list>
        </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}" />
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
        </form>
```

How to get the value in the controller that I chose on the form?

```
     @RequestMapping("/user-fonts")
public class MainController{
    @GetMapping
    public String main(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user, Model model)
    {
       Set<DBFont> fonts = user.getFont();
        model.addAttribute("fonts", fonts);
        return "Myfonts";
    }
    @PostMapping
    public String mainPost(@ModelAttribute DBFont DBfont)
    {

        System.out.println(DBfont.getNameFont());
         return "redirect:/user-fonts";
    }
```

There is a value in the database, but I get `null`, How to return the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a `name` attribute to your select, e.g. `nameFont`:

```
 <select name="nameFont">
```

This will send font selected value as POST parameter `nameFont`

Comment: Why, everything returns to me to NULL except the name??((

Comment: @crazy_deviL can you open a new question with details?

Comment: I wrote a new question